# What is the impact of OpenVPN SECLEVEL=0?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

OpenVPN throws a "signature digest algorithm too weak" error when I try to connect to a specific VPN.

A common [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049798/cannot-connect-to-openvpn-after-upgrade-to-18-04) for a workaround is using the following config:

```
tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"
```

This works, but I was unable to find any documentation about what `SECLEVEL` does. Does it just allow the less-secure cipher the VPN server offers? Or does it allow any cipher (eg also null cipher) or does it otherwise lead to a complete compromise of security?

Answer (score 7):

From [`man 1 ciphers`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html):

> The cipher string **@SECLEVEL=n** can be used at any point to set the security level to *n*, which should be a number between zero and five, inclusive. See [SSL_CTX_set_security_level](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html) for a description of what each level means.

And from [`man 3 SSL_CTX_set_security_level`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html):

> Level 0
>
> Everything is permitted. This retains compatibility with previous versions of OpenSSL.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by 'everything is permitted'. Does that mean any type of certificate is permitted', or also that no (valid) certificate is permitted?
In other words, what does it mean for the security of the connection?

Comment: @Tom I _may_ be wrong, but I'd assume the "everything" here means "every cipher" (i.e., any encryption algorithm) is accepted. If a _certificate_ is invalid, it will not be accepted, but this is something that will happen way after the cipher is decided.